# javacv sample program not running in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javacv

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String classifierName = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            classifierName = args[0];
        } else {
            System.err.println("Please provide the path to \"haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml\".");
            System.exit(1);
    }

    // Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
    Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

    // We can "cast" Pointer objects by instantiating a new object of the desired class.
    CvHaarClassifierCascade classifier = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(classifierName));
    if (classifier.isNull()) {
        System.err.println("Error loading classifier file \"" + classifierName + "\".");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // CanvasFrame is a JFrame containing a Canvas component, which is hardware accelerated.
    // It can also switch into full-screen mode when called with a screenNumber.
    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title");

    // OpenCVFrameGrabber uses opencv_highgui, but other more versatile FrameGrabbers
    // include DC1394FrameGrabber, FlyCaptureFrameGrabber, OpenKinectFrameGrabber,
    // PS3EyeFrameGrabber, VideoInputFrameGrabber, and FFmpegFrameGrabber.
    FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    grabber.start();

    // FAQ about IplImage:
    // - For custom raw processing of data, getByteBuffer() returns an NIO direct
    //   buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData.
    // - To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, you may call getBufferedImage().
    // - The createFrom() factory method can construct an IplImage from a BufferedImage.
    // - There are also a few copy*() methods for BufferedImage<->IplImage data transfers.
    IplImage grabbedImage = grabber.grab();
    int width  = grabbedImage.width();
    int height = grabbedImage.height();
    IplImage grayImage    = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage rotatedImage = grabbedImage.clone();

    // Let's create some random 3D rotation...
    CvMat randomR = CvMat.create(3, 3), randomAxis = CvMat.create(3, 1);
    // We can easily and efficiently access the elements of CvMat objects
    // with the set of get() and put() methods.
    randomAxis.put((Math.random()-0.5)/4, (Math.random()-0.5)/4, (Math.random()-0.5)/4);
    cvRodrigues2(randomAxis, randomR, null);
    double f = (width + height)/2.0;        randomR.put(0, 2, randomR.get(0, 2)*f);
                                            randomR.put(1, 2, randomR.get(1, 2)*f);
    randomR.put(2, 0, randomR.get(2, 0)/f); randomR.put(2, 1, randomR.get(2, 1)/f);
    System.out.println(randomR);

    // Objects allocated with a create*() or clone() factory method are automatically released
    // by the garbage collector, but may still be explicitly released by calling release().
    // You shall NOT call cvReleaseImage(), cvReleaseMemStorage(), etc. on objects allocated this way.
    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

    // We can allocate native arrays using constructors taking an integer as argument.
    CvPoint hatPoints = new CvPoint(3);

    // Again, FFmpegFrameRecorder also exists as a more versatile alternative.
    FrameRecorder recorder = new OpenCVFrameRecorder("output.avi", width, height);
    recorder.start();

    while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null) {
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        // Let's try to detect some faces! but we need a grayscale image...
        cvCvtColor(grabbedImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, classifier, storage,
                1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
        int total = faces.total();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
            int x = r.x(), y = r.y(), w = r.width(), h = r.height();
            cvRectangle(grabbedImage, cvPoint(x, y), cvPoint(x+w, y+h), CvScalar.RED, 1, CV_AA, 0);

            // To access the elements of a native array, use the position() method.
            hatPoints.position(0).x(x-w/10)   .y(y-h/10);
            hatPoints.position(1).x(x+w*11/10).y(y-h/10);
            hatPoints.position(2).x(x+w/2)    .y(y-h/2);
            cvFillConvexPoly(grabbedImage, hatPoints.position(0), 3, CvScalar.GREEN, CV_AA, 0);
        }

        // Let's find some contours! but first some thresholding...
        cvThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 64, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        // To check if an output argument is null we may call either isNull() or equals(null).
        CvSeq contour = new CvSeq(null);
        cvFindContours(grayImage, storage, contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),
                CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        while (contour != null && !contour.isNull()) {
            if (contour.elem_size() > 0) {
                CvSeq points = cvApproxPoly(contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),
                        storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contour)*0.02, 0);
                cvDrawContours(grabbedImage, points, CvScalar.BLUE, CvScalar.BLUE, -1, 1, CV_AA);
            }
            contour = contour.h_next();
        }

        cvWarpPerspective(grabbedImage, rotatedImage, randomR);

        frame.showImage(rotatedImage);
        recorder.record(rotatedImage);
    }
    recorder.stop();
    grabber.stop();
    frame.dispose();
}
}
```

I took the above code from the sample codes and tried to run it. I added the jar files as mentioned. All the errors and warnings vanished. but when i run the code.

I got the following errors...

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Balachander P\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core7504532540941704965.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:352)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:285)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:129)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:305)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:285)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.JavaCV.<clinit>(JavaCV.java:88)
```

I'm new to javacv and trying it for the first time. Can someone help me out with it..

Comment: Please show some code! Are you using any native libraries (seems so). Cheers!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV

Comment: the instruction did help thanks a lot.

Comment: I must also say that I have several times got into situation when JavaCV/OpenCV did not work if K-Lite coded pack was not installed. The error message was much like yours and all the paths were set correct as in the touleshooting instruction, but without codecs it failed with the same error. Took me some time to figure the reason out.

Comment: Have you able to solve your problem ? I'm also facing some problem relating to similar code. Actually about cvHaarDetectObjects() method please share your experience

Comment: following the instruction worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the library files of OpenCV(*.dll) can be found either in their default installation directory or in the system PATH which under Windows includes the current working directory. (For answers to problems frequently encountered with OpenCV on the Windows platform, please refer to Common issues with OpenCV under Windows 7.)

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Check system PATH

Answer (score 0):

It looks like opnecv is not linked properly Follow the link for step by step instructions
http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html